# 120V transistorized power supply

Tags: power-supply

Can you tell me what is the role of the transistor Q4 in this 120V power supply?

[image]

Comment: Interesting usage of a curved, dashed line to indicate a heatsink on Q1, Q3, and Q4.  Note that 200 VAC rectified is 283VDC, so 163V is being dropped by these transistors (very low efficiency.)  Today we'd almost certainly use a buck regulator to step that down to 125 VDC, then use a low-dropout linear regulator after that to get a clean 120 VDC at much higher efficiency.

Comment: The bridge rectifier is improperly implemented. The second and fourth diodes need to be reversed, with cathodes on the transformer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1 and Q4 are [cascoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode). This puts them in series and drops a roughly equal voltage across each of them reducing the \$V_{CE}\$ and power dissipation requirements on each transistor.

In this example simulation you can see the difference.
[image]

Without cascoding the pass transistor has 150 V dropped across it and dissipates 1.74 W. With cascoding one transistor drops 60 V and dissipates 500 mW, the other 90 V and 775 mW. By adjusting the bias resistors on the first transistor it should be possible to get them pretty much even so they both drop and dissipate half the voltage and power.

At low load currents most of the excess voltage will drop across the transistors and the voltage sharing will be more important to keep the transistors within their \$V_{CE}\$ ratings. At higher load currents the 1.2k resistor will start to drop more of the voltage and the dissipation sharing will become more important to keep the transistors within their \$P_D\$ ratings.

Comment: thanks for all,

Answer (score 2):

There is up to 160V difference between the rectified source (280V DC) and the output (120V DC). It looks like Q4 is there to "share" some of that difference with Q1. This happens because the resistor divider consisting of the 19kΩ and 30kΩ resistors, places the base and emitter of Q4 somewhere near the middle of the potentials at each end.

Since both transistors Q1 and Q4 pass the same current, this means that power dissipation is also shared between the two.

Q4's role seems to be to share power dissipation between those two transistors, effectively doubling the current that a single transistor Q1 could tolerate alone.

Comment: Agree, but add that the huge 1200 ohm 30W resistor also shares the common current, and is also a major "share-er" of power dissipation along with Q1, Q4.

Comment: @glen_geek I did say "up to 160V", I just didn't say why.